# Building nxt_lejos fails finding rosjava.mk

Tags: ros, nxt, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm currently trying to connect Lego Mindstorms NXT to ROS via rosjava as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_lejos/Installation), but the installation fails at nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy with

> Makefile:1: /home/andreas/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/rosjava.mk: File or directory not found

I believe this is due to rosjava now using gradle instead of the previous rosmake driven build process, but unfortunately I've got no idea how to fix this. I don't want to revert back to an earlier version of rosjava.

Is it possible to use the current rosjava with nxt_lejos?

Best regards,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32581/building-nxt_lejos-fails-finding-rosjava.mk/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get a snapshot build from the SVN snapshot directory which will have getTurnRate in it. However, nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy does not work very well, and I may remove it. getTurnRate was a mistake and I will get rid of it some time. You are better off running nxt_lejos_proxy, which should work with lejos 0.9.1. This requires that you run the ROSResponder sample on the NXT. It works quite well for me. You will need to get ROSResponder from SVN. I need to find a solution to the hard-coded dependencies in the gradle build file. I am currently waiting for a response of my "rosjava message serialization problems" query  before I do further work on nxt_lejos as it is stopping odometry and imu messages working properly, which means that parts of the navigation stack do not work.

---

Originally posted by [LawrieGriffiths](https://answers.ros.org/users/1997/lawriegriffiths/) with karma: 131 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on 2012-08-28**:
Ignoring nxt_lejos_lcp_proxy in nxt_lejos/settings.gradle did the trick for me :) Thank you very much!